# Differentiate none-exist parent and empty property when executing LINQ with Entity Framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework-6

I build LINQ expression and then execute with Entity Framework with `IQueryable` extension method `ToArrayAsync`.

I have two queries:

```
value(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[Person]).MergeAs(AppendOnly).Where(currentValue => (currentValue.PersonId == 111)).SelectMany(Param_0 => Param_0.Friends)
value(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[Person]).MergeAs(AppendOnly).Where(currentValue => (currentValue.PersonId == 111)).Select(Param_0 => Param_0.FirstName)
```

My question is: when the person does not exist at all or the person exists but its friends is an empty collection, I got the same result now, if there any way to differentiate these two cases? The person does not exist at all vs the person exists but its friends is an empty collection. There is no intention to execute `IQueryable` twice like first person first.

The same question if the property is single value like `FirstName`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use `Select` (after `Where()`) to project the `Person` object into an anonymous type which contains both the `Person` object and whether or not it exists (or any other `Person` field/property).

If you share what you plan to do with your differentiation, I can share more details about how that could be achieved.

Comment: thanks, I expect

If Person does not exist, then should throw some exceptions I can catch like Parent entity does not exist.

If Person exists and property does not have value, then empty or null value returned.

Or return empty or null result with additional flag indicates parent exists or not.

Comment: It sounds like what you want is null propagation. Use `...Where(currentValue => (currentValue.PersonId == 111))?.SelectMany(Param_0 => Param_0.Friends)`, then test the result for null.

Comment: This will not resolve the issue as if I got a result null, I do not know whether the person does not exist or the person exist but its Friends is null/empty.

I need to differentiate these two cases when I execute a LINQ shown above, 

Case 1: The person does not exist 

 Case 2: The person exist but its Friends is null/empty.